# Copy quotas to a new server

Tags: linux, ext4, quota

I'm migrating a client from their current server to new servers with DRBD replicaton.
They are using quotas and I'm wondering if there is an easy way to export them on the old server and import them on the new server ?
I googled a bit and I guess it should be possible by mixing repquota and setquota, but maybe there is a tool for that already ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up scripting it myself quickly :

```
_DST="/ha.0/"

_SRC="/root/quotas.txt"

while read -u10 _line
do
    _user="$(echo ${_line} | cut -f 1 -d ' ')"
    _bsoft="$(echo ${_line} | cut -f 4 -d ' ')"
    _bhard="$(echo ${_line} | cut -f 5 -d ' ')"
    _fsoft="$(echo ${_line} | cut -f 7 -d ' ')"
    _fhard="$(echo ${_line} | cut -f 8 -d ' ')"
    setquota -u "${_user}" "${_bsoft}" "${_bhard}" "${_fsoft}" "${_fhard}" "${_DST}"
done 10< "${_SRC}"
```

Not amazing but it worked well. Just copy the output of the old server's repquota in /root/quotas.txt and run that script on the new server !